# DocuSign.eSign, Version=4.3.0.0, could not be resolved on the .NET Framework assembly "System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting below error when adding reference of assembly DocuSign.eSign.dll and build the solution. I tried with version 4.3.0 and 4.1.1 for DocuSign.eSign.dll.

The primary reference "DocuSign.eSign, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7fca6fcbbc219ede, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.2.0.0" than the version "4.0.0.0" in the current target framework.

Please note - I am using VS 2012 with latest framework 4.5.

Comment: Any chance you can get VS 2017/2019 with latest version of .NET?

Comment: No, company restricted to use VS 2012 as company have only license of VS 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The SDK requires](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/) at least version 4.5.2 of the .NET Framework or above.
VS 2012 is pretty old, but Microsoft says you can still upgrade your .NET Framework to 4.5.2 See here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637

Comment: thank you for help. Now we call API with web client

Comment: Happy to help, do you mind marking the question as "answered."

Comment: Actually we start calling using HttpWebClient instead of using DocuSign Library. Because we can not upgrade framework as this is live project and need to take care of lot of thing. I have open another query for same task and i will you there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817707/getting-400-bad-request-message-while-requesting-for-access-token-from-docusign/61826022#61826022