# Getting 400 bad request message while requesting for access token from DocuSign API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am able generate access token with docusign site by using link  https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator

But when try to get access token in our system using c# code then getting message (The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.)

I follow the authenticate process mentioned in below link.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant

I able to get authentication code. I used this authentication code to hit API (https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token).

Below is my code sample

```
string integrationKey = "key removed";
string secretKey = "key removed";
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
string apiStoreConsumer =    "removed";
 httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + apiStoreConsumer);
 using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
  {
   string input = "authorization_code&authorization_code= <authentication code goes here>;

   streamWriter.Write(input);
   streamWriter.Flush();
   streamWriter.Close();
 }

WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Query:

Why am I getting 400 error?
Do we have any expiry time for access token, if yes then how long?
Does authentication code get change for every request?

Please help me on this.

Thank You!

Comment: According to their documentation, authorization code is only valid for 2 minutes. Also in the body of your request parameters should be `grant_type=authorization_code&code=YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE`. Did you try this way? Also you should remove any secret key from your example code when posting your question.

Comment: please don't share your secrets in a public forum, this is just bad example to junior engineers who may see this and think it's no big deal

Comment: thank you Inbar. I removed keys. Really it was mistake. I passed grant_type=authorization_code&code=YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE in body. you can check code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a library for OAuth in .NET/C#.
If you want to see how this is done, please [clone this repo.](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp)
The issue is that you need to first get a code and then exchange it for a token. There are 2 steps involved if you do this manually.
The first step requires you to authenticate the user in a browser before you can call any API.
During that step you need to pass in your integration key and redirect back to your URL.
Once redirected back you'll receive a code that can be exchanged for an access token using the API call you had talks about.

Comment: Thank you, I understood the flow, as you said and also from docusign documentation. In this approach, there is an manual interaction. Actually in our requirement we don't want any manual interaction. Is there anyway or other API through which we got token based on secret keys  without going manual interaction. Please help.

Comment: I need small clarification. Do we every time follow these 2 steps(first get authentication code, then 2 step to request for access token). But in our requirement, we don't want any manual interaction. we want to get access code based integration key and secret key, or follow these steps without redirect to some other URL to get authentication code. Our requirement is
We get messages of signer body from any other system
We do some operation and send it to DocuSign for initiate signing ceremony.
We want develop system which do all above steps with any manual interaction.

Comment: than you will have to use JWT, not Auth Code Grant, the code example I linked in my answer shows you both.

Comment: Great. I will go through documentation for JWT. Can we use JWT with visual studio 2012 and framework 4.5 ?

Comment: You would need to at least have 4.5.2 for the library to work

Comment: As per your suggestion, I am implementing JWT for our application. Working on step 2 to create JWT token.
I able to header and body, but getting error while encode the signature mean for below part.
rs256sign(<base64URL-encoded header>.<base64URL-encoded body>)

I am using jwt.net library for this. Please note I am using framework 4.5 of visual studio 2012. Please help on this.

Comment: var h = new { alg = "RS256", typ = "JWT" }; var payload1 = new Dictionary<string, object>()  { {"iss", ""}, {"sub", ""},   {"iat", 1589979664},  {"exp", 1590008421},    {"aud", "account-d.docusign.com"}, {"scope", "signature impersonation"}     };  byte[] pBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload1, Formatting.None));  byte[] hBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(n, Formatting.None));  string Sign = Base64UrlEncode(hBytes) + "." + Base64UrlEncode(pBytes);  string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(Sign, privateKey, JwsAlgorithm.RS256);

Comment: is this a different issue now? I think you were getting a 400 error, I'm confused what is the new issue. Maybe you can ask s new question?

Comment: Actually we drop the previous approach to get access token by authentication code. As I already asked in previous question of this thread that authentication code is of 2 step process which is not suitable for our requirement. So we change the approach and going to implement JWT approach to get access token. There now i facing this new issue. Do we initiate new thread for this or you are good to answer. Please help me.

Comment: I don't have all the information about your new issue. Exactly what you're doing, what code you're calling, what error you're getting